# Typescript Type Guard Recursive Checking

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

I am building a Typescript guard that restricts content from going through certain paths or APIs within a codebase.

The idea being the compiler should reject input if it or any part of its content has been marked as restricted.

This works surprisingly well in the majority of my test cases but unfortunately completely **fails when** the restricted content is part of a **deeply nested object** eg: `{grandparent: {parent: {child: myRestrictedContent}}}`

I have attempted multiple approaches to recursive checking within the `RestrictedContentGuard` all without success.

I have replicated the issue in a [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBKwDOMoEsDGMwAJgMIQB2RVAPACoB8cAvHHXAGRwDecA%20nwhgAhgEcArsAEAuOAHIoWHASJlK1GHLgBfANwAofaEiwEyVABFgwMBmx5CJclWC1GLNnFDVimOAEEoKGFEGlwKADNgKDgAVSZ9OCS4AH50YGFiSgAbREDg0KsbO2VHNRdaeIZE5Nl2b1dfOAgAIwArYEI4GuTU9PsVJ3VXGBpuAG0wOHC4AGtgRAgItgBdWSLbJQdVZw16SZWGbWrepNkS7aGK0cYDRIB6e7gACQgAdwQIOABbYXmEAAWuD8inw4igmFwADdgLk4JgMlB8ADAag6OYUoljNB4EgUP1SjthlQAOLiYRQYj0JiseogHx%20C6Dcp7dw9NIUYAwqA9WQTeaIaYUOYLJarOrjAUrLz0xqMrbM3YjfZSpgcrnROASqV6U6GfSPOAAMXEFEIuEo8IBEHE2WIcAoEHgwmy2XecGEFEFrQ6XWgcDAUCE0SQPwp83twj8%20GJuIBQfEAHMAQA6fQRU3my3fRAABSD%20CwmGg1IAFDHrucFWUlaTyZTqQBKHg9OAV4vZYApt2J8uxxsGbSGQ0AWXDJA98oGZTgtZgABoHV8RKYxTAAagfZ14FuuongmAUcCPa73hOYF8WqhAxBC5gEcQ03jULnosXhawNkya7GxhFcBCMAAHLCN8wCyAMFCJou2RRsBoHgfCyhQYuwiJohFDiN8V5QMcdztvAOavhClqsNw-6ASBYGyHIABCrRyDBcFUYhdGeuxjEeuhsgAAwpgArNok5wMR753AaTx0EocAAIxwAAtHA4y5v4ADKqkAKIWGscSQlBqJwIo06qG2sbdERBZFtApZEW%20lADvqhpSdgcAAEwKUpKnqVpOmxHpiYGUZhIThWGh%20DeKCwLgWD6BZt5WVANl5nZFAphR2AsQ5cV3sWiW2SRqWwRlCEORJbDSQAzB5ylqZp2myH54QBeuqBBZc9qhSMcBvLg64zMI8LgkGibCEQsV5pZ97WdwnVULI%20XvtopVOdJAAs1VGv4ACSAAyPkNf5gXViZs3wD1fXCgNxDWGAcKctgE72OIhDgsA435vFU2Jdw90wHyv3-Uo83JQV2hg8tkkAPIWJDDUUNdgGeva1ofBeYb-C1hnHSFZmJvW9qguCkIws0MRvC6syAgmyYGfuwiHs0yxQi6kiYEAA) which nicely showcases the point of failure, alternatively I have included the same implementation below:

```js
export type RestrictedContent<T> = T & { __opaque__: 'restrictedContent' };

export type DeepRestrictedContent<T> = T extends Array<infer U> 
    ? ReadonlyArray<DeepRestrictedContent<U>>
    : T extends object 
      ? RestrictedContent<{[p in keyof T]: DeepRestrictedContent<T[p]>}>
      : RestrictedContent<T>;

 // How to make this recursively search the Type?
 export type RestrictedContentGuard<T> = T extends RestrictedContent<T> 
   ? never
   : {[key in keyof T]: T[key] extends RestrictedContent<T[key]> ? never : T[key]};     


// Function should not allow any object or property marked as content through.
function myProcessor<T>(content: RestrictedContentGuard<T>) {
    console.log(content);
}

// Marked as Restricted Content, no part of the object object graph is allowed to be processed.
type Person = DeepRestrictedContent<{firstName: string, lastName: string, age: number}>;

const myPerson = {firstName: 'Bob', lastName: 'Banana', age: 0.5} as Person;


// Test 1 - [PASSED]: Using the restricted content 
myProcessor(myPerson);


// Test 2 - [PASSED]: Using the restricted contents properties
myProcessor(myPerson.firstName);
myProcessor(myPerson.lastName);

// Test 3 - [PASSED]: Using the restricted content within a surrogate
myProcessor({content: myPerson});

// Test 4 - [FAILED]: Using the restricted content within a deeply nested structure
myProcessor({nest: {nest: {nest: myPerson}}});

// TODO: Understand how to make the restricted content guard recursive or walk through the graph of values
```

It is worth mentioning I have omitted parts of the implementation that deals with both arrays and null referencing in order to narrow in on the problem.

Thank you for reading

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mZ5aeN) meet your needs? If so, I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am  I missing?

Comment: @jcalz That is indeed solving the problem! I would really love a breakdown, I could not find much in the ways of documentation to describe the pattern you are using to achieve it.

Comment: I'll write up an answer when I get a chance. Might be a few hours from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your definitions, I'd first factor out your [type brand](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal) to its own name, for east of reference later:

```
type RestrictMarker = { __opaque__: 'restrictedContent' };
export type RestrictedContent<T> = T & RestrictMarker;
```

Then instead of checking somethhing like `T extends RestrictedContent<T>`, we can just check `T extends RestrictMarker`, which amounts to pretty much the same thing, but is more straightforward.

---

Next, I think it makes sense to first build a *detector* to see if any property or subproperty has that `RestrictMarker` in it.  Here's one way to do that:

```
type HasRestricted<T, Y = unknown, N = never> = T extends RestrictMarker ? Y :
  unknown extends { [K in keyof T]: HasRestricted<T[K]> }[keyof T] ? Y : N;
```

The idea is that `HasRestricted<T, Y, N>` will evaluate to `Y` if and only if `T` is restricted somewhere, and evaluate to `N` otherwise.  The `Y` and `N` are not strictly necessary here, but sometimes it's helpful to choose what happens in each case.  The [defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) are [the top type `unknown`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type) for `Y` and [the bottom type `never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) for `N`.

It's a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) which immediately evaluates to `Y` if `T` is itself a `RestrictMarker`-compatible type.  Otherwise, it recurses, generating the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `HasRestricted<T[K]>` for all properties `T[K]` of `T`.  The union of `unknown` with any type `X` will be `unknown`, while the union of `never` with any type `X` will be `X`.  That means the union of all `HasRestricted<T[K]>` will only be `never` if *no* subtree is restricted, and otherwise it will be `unknown`.  So the check `unknown extends ⋯` will pass if any of the subtrees are restricted, and will fail only if no subtrees are restricted.  Hence if the check passes we return `Y`, and only if it fails do we return `N`.

Note that it's possible for there to be edge cases where this detector doesn't do what you like (deeply recursive conditional types always seem to have such edge cases), but hopefully one can tweak this to work in such a situation.

---

And now we're ready to write `RestrictedContentGuard<T>`. There are a number of ways to write this, but the one that changes your approach the least (and leaves it as `T extends ⋯ ? ⋯ : ⋯` for inference) is:

```
type RestrictedContentGuard<T> = T extends HasRestricted<T> ? never : T;
```

The check `T extends HasRestricted<T>` looks like `T extends unknown` if it's restricted, which will pass.  Or like `T extends never` if it's not restricted, which will fail (unless `T` happens to be `never`, but we don't have to worry about that, really).  Okay, let's test it:

```
myProcessor(myPerson); // error
myProcessor(myPerson.firstName); // error
myProcessor(myPerson.lastName); // error
myProcessor({ content: myPerson }); // error
myProcessor({ nest: { nest: { nest: myPerson } } }); // error
myProcessor({ other: "abc" }); // okay
```

Looks good. `myProcessor()` rejects anything with a `RestrictMarker` anywhere in its descendant properties, while it accepts a regular object type like `{other: string}`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/FAFwngDgpgBASlAziATgSwMYgLIEMUDWUKMAvDAN4wD61A9hLgI4CuUtAXDAOQpKqYQUACYBhOgDshU7jAC+AbmBQAHhDooQMcNHj90WEeKlQpAHgAqAPjIwLMAGR7kBnPiIolytRq07YACJQUBAILoJGktIgljbk9qrSwogwAIIoKLhgZmgSAGbEMACqVsAwMAD8erjCkgA2YOmZ2UEhYQKGYlGmMSWl5VwJKkkpdABGAFZQWGWVzh1CXSbmVADaANIwuTBEYHR5dgC6XK2h+hFL0ZYbhzZy-TBc7a6RyzHWXv4wABK4iM8XSwAGhgAE1bCwJAQJHQAO4SEEAOVsEigADdiHE7DBEqZkvNXHhCIUquCOLNIdC4RIccM8Sk1pttrt9kcuL9-udOtd1rd5KsWQcLIc5mSYIjPpBYADOsZogBxFj4YSxWxDEY-P4yxaqqqojEkQZePKQrBoSQwAC2YAACig6BgkIgNLEABQYbpSJ5cxZynqK5WxACUlFmHokzrqUAAdHU6ABzd2ekBBpRyYCgKUwG3EZ008inbWvK5UPJoFDIRG4S1QLjhCTxkF1P4gKs1usCBsg3Dx2swCQsS1jQr3Lzh5BW225i3kUvlyvVvvcABC424TZbbaXy9wEl3uHXMB7fYADNGAKzyI8pHMVyRea12h1OjSux-TiSpmAAem-OIyGjAI+9qOogzooG+U53hI0ZlhWraLl+v7-vaKBAbaIEvhB77QbGm6IQoP5-sQqHoU+oHga6VDhtEXA4Xm8hIcRAFocBz5ga+VCosgXBcfwvH9vxk63gxchXnITEoYBbEUZxMB0CAAAWxBcAARLgYwYKpjGEchdAEFkGZAA)

Comment: Apologies for the delay in replying and a big thank you for the very detailed answer, as you mentioned edge cases are likely to surface and already a fair few have me struggling through. 

The majority of these have been around types that are `null | undefined | any` or evaluate in some way to those. 

The unexpected **and unresolved** issue has been types that are circular.

Comment: I'm not really prepared to delve into that here. You could try to build a recursion limiter and only check to some maximum depth.